# Как спарсить ссылки с помощью jsoup с сайта?

Tags: java, jsoup, парсер

```
public class NewThread extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... arg) {

        try {

            doc = Jsoup.connect("http://www.novostiit.net/category/company").get();

            add = doc.select("li.cat-item");
            link = doc.select("li.cat-item a");
            String linkHref = link.attr("abs:href");
            titleList.clear();

            for (Element content : add) {
                titleList.add(content.text());
                titleList.add(linkHref);
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }
```

Получилось лишь спарсить первую ссылку, но мне надо каждую. Что я упустил?

[image: 123]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Что я упустил?

Перед циклом Вы получаете:

```
String linkHref = link.attr("abs:href");
```

и далее в цикле нигде не изменяете эту переменную, следовательно, она везде дублируется.

---

**Данную задачу можно решить несколько проще:**

Смотрим исходный код этих элементов:

```
<li class="cat-item cat-item-20"><a href="http://www.novostiit.net/category/it" title="IT технологии, новости информационных технологий, новости it технологий, новости технологии, новости it технологии ">IT технологии</a> (407)
</li>
<li class="cat-item cat-item-18"><a href="http://www.novostiit.net/category/video" title="видео новости">Видео</a> (484)
</li>
...
```

У всех элементов атрибут `class` начинается с `cat-item cat-item` (и на данной странице нет других элементов с подобными атрибутами), следовательно, получить их можно так:

```
Document page = Jsoup.connect("http://www.novostiit.net/category/company").get();
Elements categories = page.select("li[class^='cat-item cat-item']");
```

А получить название и ссылку, так:

```
for (Element category : categories) {
    System.out.println(category.select("a").text());
    System.out.println(category.select("a").attr("href") + "\n");
}
```

Вывод на консоль:

```
IT технологии
http://www.novostiit.net/category/it

Видео
http://www.novostiit.net/category/video

Все новости
http://www.novostiit.net/category/novosti

Гаджеты
http://www.novostiit.net/category/gadgety

Игры
http://www.novostiit.net/category/igry

...
```

PS. У Jsoup есть очень удобный [инструмент](https://try.jsoup.org/).